# Ubuntu 22.04: crazy kernel updates

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 22.04

today I booted my Ubuntu 22.04 as usual and **Software Updates Tool** asked me to install/update very old kernels. Also, it installed the 6.1.0-oem.

Why?

[image: Screenshot]

**Edit for GUIVERC**

Into APT logs (/var/log/apt/*-gz) I see that the only installations are the official 5.19.0-46.generic (Ubuntu 22.04 Gnome).

The *Software Update Manager* currenlty show me the package into the above screenshot.

The following is my `/boot` folder content:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 lug  1 10:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root     4096 mag 19 21:03 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   270051 giu  7 16:23 config-5.19.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   270051 giu 21 16:38 config-5.19.0-46-generic
drwx------  4 root root     4096 gen  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root     4096 lug  1 10:19 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 lug  1 09:39 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.19.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 37572599 lug  1 09:39 initrd.img-5.19.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 71440610 giu 30 13:04 initrd.img-5.19.0-46-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 lug  1 10:19 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.19.0-46-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182800 feb  6  2022 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184476 feb  6  2022 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184980 feb  6  2022 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  6438389 giu  7 16:23 System.map-5.19.0-45-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  6438424 giu 21 16:38 System.map-5.19.0-46-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 lug  1 09:39 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.19.0-45-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 12221544 giu  7 16:23 vmlinuz-5.19.0-45-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 12220712 giu 21 16:43 vmlinuz-5.19.0-46-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 lug  1 10:19 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.19.0-46-generic
```

I suspect an issue for the *Software Manager Tool* because by the apt cli the following are the only proposed upgrades:

```
 ~ $ apt list --upgradable 
Listing... Done
libnvidia-cfg1-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnvidia-common-530/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 all [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnvidia-compute-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnvidia-compute-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnvidia-decode-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnvidia-decode-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnvidia-encode-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnvidia-encode-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnvidia-extra-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnvidia-fbc1-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnvidia-fbc1-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnvidia-gl-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libnvidia-gl-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
linux-modules-nvidia-530-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1+2 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1]
linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-46-generic/jammy-updates 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1+2 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1]
nvidia-compute-utils-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
nvidia-driver-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
nvidia-kernel-common-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
nvidia-kernel-source-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
nvidia-utils-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-530/jammy-updates 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
```

Comment: You can have multiple kernel stacks installed; though by default a Ubuntu product only has one stack installed by default, users can add other stacks too...  eg. my LTS install has both the GA & HWE kernel stacks, thus I'll receive multiple kernels on upgrades.... Your system appears to have the GA + OEM kernel stacks; likely you've installed them (*what is installed is determined by packages installed at install; you didn't mention what 22.04 product you had installed, plus what was added post-install by users with `sudo` access*)

Comment: This is not my case. I have only the 5.19.0-46-generic until yesterday. Today asked me to upgrade kernel which I never installed.

Comment: 5.19 is from the HWE kernel stack (6.2 currently being in *proposed*).  I'd suggest exploring your *apt* logs to see why (*in the past*) they were installed by a user with `sudo` access.. as that is what would explain what you describe; at least to me..   A user installing stuff without realizing the consequences.  Note you've still not said what 22.04 product either (*though install media sets defaults too*) even though a GUI attachment appears to indicate a desktop install; we're limited by details you provide...

Comment: I provide more detail by editing my post...

Comment: Same on 23.04. I had only generic kernels, no new packages in months, previous updates OK, and all of a sudden `update-manager` wants to install `oracle` and `lowlatency` kernels. Install failed, and now both kernel image packages are half-conf. It’s unclear what’s happening…

Comment: I also had the same problem, precisely as described, and was only able to recover by switching boot disk (an image I had done a couple of months ago).
It installs all those kernels in succession; crazy.

Comment: I opened a bug request that you can find at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/707171 . Today the problems seems to be solved, but it was just luck!

Comment: Look at https://askubuntu.com/a/1475864/1696485 .

Comment: I had the same issue in 22.04.2 LTS with a lot of new kernels added through the software updater. After they were installed, it opened again to remove unused software which removed those kernel versions. I confirmed that, and after this it wanted to repeat the process. o.O Instead I rebootet and next time, the system upgrader tool opened to perform a dist-upgrade. I am still with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS but now with kernel 6.1.0-1050-oem, before it was 5.15.0-76-generic. Sadly, some software like Nvidia driver and VirtualBox stopped to work with the new 6.1.0 kernel, for now.

Comment: The mentioned drivers don't work because you are using the OEM version. To fix it unistall the 6.1.0 and installa 5.19.0-46.generic .

Answer (score 4):

I removed the 6.1 kernel with the following command, which got things back to normal, more or less, i.e. a 5.19 kernel.

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-6.1.0-1015-oem linux-image-unsigned-6.1.0-1015-oem
```

For some reason I needed both package names otherwise apt indicated it was going to install linux-image-unsigned-6.1.0-1015-oem if I removed just linux-image-6.1.0-1015-oem.

I still have a problem where the additional drivers UI now says that I'm running a manually installed driver for my NVidia 1060.

Comment: Very similar to my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Problems started for me too with the weird kernel installs, but I stopped that and after reboot, the software upgrader tool popped up which I confirmed. This would be the first step to fix it:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

After that, I had the new kernel 6.1.0-1015-oem, before it was a 5.15.x "generic" kernel. But kernel dependend software like Nvidia driver and Virtualbox did not work anymore.

```
sudo dkms autoinstall
```

and rebooting fixed that. (Maybe the Nvidia driver has to be reinstalled once. I did reinstall because I removed & purged it when it was not working.)