# 23.04 Update automatically installing lowlatency + oracle kernels on a generic system?

Tags: kernel, updates, update-manager, ubuntu-drivers, 23.04

Just a few minutes ago, there were updates waiting so I chose to install them (from the GUI), and much to my surprise, I see that it tries to install `oracle` and `lowlatency` kernels. The process failed during config phase and now the following packages are “half-conf”.

```
iF  linux-image-6.2.0-1005-oracle                  6.2.0-1005.5                               amd64        Signed kernel image oracle
iF  linux-image-6.2.0-1007-lowlatency              6.2.0-1007.7                               amd64        Signed kernel image lowlatency
```

Considering :

- I only had generic kernels installed
- I didn’t install any new packages in months
- Previous recent updates worked with no problem

Can someone explain what just happened ?

**EDIT :**

I found here and there, posts and bug reports that are hinting towards an unrequested kernel stack change :

- [Bug #2025538 “Unrequested kernel update”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-nvidia-5.19/+bug/2025538)
- [Bug #2025537 “chrome Check failed”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/2025537)
- [upgrade - Ubuntu 22.04: crazy kernel updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475574/ubuntu-22-04-crazy-kernel-updates)
- [nvidia - Aften normal update and reboot, Ubuntu 22 fails to boot with drivers, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475650/aften-normal-update-and-reboot-ubuntu-22-fails-to-boot-with-drivers-how-to-fix)

So, 22.04 and 23.04 seem to be affected.

My (wild) guess is, it’s related to `ubuntu-drivers-common` and only concerns people with an Nvidia GPU, the system being hinted towards a wrong driver from another kernel stack.

Comment: @user535733 Do you have the proprietary Nvidia driver installed ? I’m suspecting the problem may come from `ubuntu-drivers-common` that decided to install drivers from kernel stacks that were not installed, which then brought the kernel images, because dependencies

Comment: @user535733 Indeed, maybe they are not, but it’s not like they were submitted years apart, it’s in the same time frame (<24h). Moreover, some posts explicitly complain about kernels from another stack being installed, which imho is more than sort of similar.

Comment: `pkcon -v refresh`  and  `pkcon -v get-updates` please. Mabe packagekit is to blame for.

Comment: I’ve already uninstalled the kernels as well as associated modules and Nvidia drivers that were wrongly installed. I ran an `ubuntu-drivers install` too, that brought my Nvidia drivers to a more recent version (was 515, now 535). Now my system looks up to date, at least that’s what _update-notifier_ says. I will update my question later to reflect this, but this seems to point towards `ubuntu-drivers-common` suggesting driver packages from non-installed kernels. Considering what I did already, do you think running those `pkcon` commands would still be useful from a diagnostic standpoint ?